# bubble custom events down

Tags: javascript, jquery

Events only bubble up, but sometimes one needs to trigger a custom event on a parent element and make it call all the handlers on any of its children if they have a listener bound to them. What's the best way to do this in jQuery?

Answer (score 3):

so far I came up with this:

```
$(startingParentElement).addBack().find('*').each(function(index,element){ 
    $(element).triggerHandler('myCustomEventName');
});
```

- *[triggerHandler()](http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/)* ensures the event doesn't bubble back up
- *each()* is needed because *triggerHandler()* is only performed on the first item in the matched collection
- *[addBack()](http://api.jquery.com/addBack/)* ensures a handler bound to the *startingParentElement* is called too

Comment: addBack() is an interesting method